# How do I get Objective Sharpie to recognize framework dependency header paths?

Tags: c#, swift, xamarin.ios, objective-sharpie, xamarin.ios-binding

I have created a framework with Xcode that will be used as a **Swift native binding** for a Xamarin iOS app. This framework has another framework dependency (GoogleMobileAds).

My `xcodebuild` steps for both `arm64` and `x86_64` are successful, but the Objective Sharpie step is failing with this error: `/Projects/XamarinGadmBinding/XamarinGadmBinding.framework/Headers/XamarinGadmBinding-Swift.h:192:9: fatal error: module 'GoogleMobileAds' not found @import GoogleMobileAds;`

The GoogleMobileAds header files are located in the path `/Projects/XamarinGadmBinding/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers`

How do I get Objective Sharpie to recognize the `GoogleMobileAds.framework` header path? As far as I can tell, you cannot pass multiple header paths in the `sharpie bind --scope` parameter.

If it helps, this is my sharpie bind call from the build script I created.

`sharpie bind --sdk=iphoneos$IOS_SDK_VERSION --output="$XAM_OUTPUT_PATH/ApiDefinitions" --namespace="$NAMESPACE" --scope="./$PROJECT_NAME.framework/Headers/" "./$PROJECT_NAME.framework/Headers/$PROJECT_NAME-Swift.h" -v`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `*` to indicate/include multiple headers. Sample code is below,

```
sharpie bind \
-sdk iphoneos15.5 \
./AppLovinSDK.framework/Headers/*.h \
-scope AppLovinSDK.framework/Headers \
-c -F .
```